# Observer, Notification, Delegate swift ios8

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, delegates, notifications

I'm looking for some advice as how to best implement something which I think might be an observer, might be a multicast delegate or perhaps i'll just use notification enter.

I'm creating a `DataManager` class that connects to various data sources and produces a common data format.

#### Example:

We can generate a `LocationMessage` from either **Internal Core Location**, **File Playback**, **Network Socket provided location**, etc.

The data type returned is a `LocationMessage` that has a common format, which can also be converted into a `CLLocation` if necessary.

In my current "multi-delegate" model if you want to get location updates you have to implement the `LocationConsumer` protocol which defines

```
func didUpdateLocation(newLocation: LocationMessage) 
{
    println("\(__FUNCTION__)   \(newLocation)")
}
```

Then you would

```
//Instantiate a data manager
let dm : DataManager = DataManager()

//Register yourself as a delegate
dm.addLocationDelegate(self)
```

Internally when we get new location data the following is called:

```
    let closure = {
        (delegate : LocationDataConsumer) -> () in
        dispatch_async(self.delegateQueue) {
            delegate.didUpdateLocation(parsedLocation)
        }
    }
    locationDelegates.map(closure)
```

where `locationDelegates` is an array of `[LocationConsumer]`

### Discussion

So, first off this obviously isn't really following a delegate pattern because you aren't supposed to have multiple delegates.

What I really like about the current approach, however, is it seems very clean to use a protocol in order to identify a class as caring about a specific data type.  What I'm uncomfortable with, however, is "breaking" the standard delegate pattern.

From doing some reading I think the most appropriate approach would be to use a **Notification** Pattern, however, I feel from a coding point of view there is more maintenance involved (although I could be wrong).  The simplicity of just implementing the protocol with this delegate method and calling `addDelegate` is lost with Notifications.  I assume I have to specifically register for each notification i care about - correct?

I could not do something like:

```
class notificaitonClass : LocationNotifiee, WeatherNotifiee {
```

}

So I guess my question is

- 1:  Have I implemented an Observer Pattern
- 2:  What are the downsides of my current approach
- 3:  Is there a way to define a swift protocol which will cause the class that implements it to automatically subscribe to a set of notifications
- 4: What would be a better approach ?

(Hope this isn't too vague)

Comment: Personally I would just use `NSNotificationCenter`.  If you wanted to abstract the `userInfo` bit so that you actually received objects that were location updates or weather updates then you could create an object that registered as the notification receiver and delivered the specific object to your consuming class using a delegate pattern - you would have one "receiver" object per object that wanted to receive the data so you would have one delegate per object

Comment: try: https://github.com/jonasman/MulticastDelegate

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @JefferyThomas. What you've done is perfectly valid, but neither Swift nor Objective-C has the concept of a multicast delegate as a standard design pattern.

That's not to say there is anything wrong with it. Having an array of objects that conform to a given protocol is perfectly valid, as is using the map function to invoke a closure on all the objects in that array. Voila, instant multicast delegate.

Cocoa/Cocoa Touch programmers (like me) are apt to look at you funny if you use that term, simply because the term "delegate" has a fairly narrow meaning in Cocoa, and that meaning does not cover multicast delegates.

It looks to me like you've got the design for your multicast delegate pretty much "mapped out" (pun intended) so go for it if that is a good fit for what you need to do. You're not breaking the delegate design pattern - you're implementing a different design pattern that is not widely used on the platform, but is nevertheless perfectly valid and useful.

When I first started reading your question I thought "delegates are one-to-one. Notifications are a much better fit." That's because, as a typical Cocoa/Cocoa Touch developer, the term "delegate" had a narrow meaning for me - one that didn't cover multicast delegates. However, before I even googled the term, I was pretty sure what you meant, and  I was thinking about arrays of objects that conform to a common protocol and the map function.

Notifications are another perfectly valid way to solve the problem. It strikes me that a difference between notifications and multicast delegates is who does the work. In multicast delegates, the sender has to maintain a list of targets (I hesitate to call them delegates) and send the desired message(s) to each.

In notifications, the sender doesn't know or care who's listening. The sender just shoots up a signal flare and the burden is on the listener(s) to care and respond. KVO is similar to notifications in that regard.

### EDIT:

Thinking about this a little more, I don't think the map function is the right choice. Map is intended to take a source array, perform some mutating operation on each element, and return the mutated elements in a new array. It creates a new array, which you ignore.

For your multicast delegate design pattern you don't need to transform (map) a source array into a destination array. You need to have each element in the array perform a task.

It would be better to use the forEach method. This line

```
locationDelegates.map(closure)
```

Would look like this instead:

```
locationDelegates.foreach
{
  closure()
}
```

(I think I have that syntax correct - I'm working mostly in Objective-C lately and getting rusty in Swift.  )

Comment: you can use my own multicast delegate written in swift: https://github.com/jonasman/MulticastDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow isn't the best forum to answer this question, you should try [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). But what the heck, here is my quick answer.

#### Don't call it a delegate

In Objective C/Swift delegate has a specific meaning and the pattern you describe doesn't fit. Call it event handler, call it change callbacks, heck, call it multi-delegate (ala `dm.addLocationMultiDelegate(self)`): just don't confuse people by overloading the term delegate.

#### Reconsider notifications

You control what the notifications are and when they are sent. You could have a `DataMangerDidUpdateLocationNotification` which could be posted from any source to any receiver. In `userInfo`, you can a `DataMangerSourceKey` if you need to keep track of who posted the notification.

In addition, you can generalize it even more. You could have a `DataMangerDidChangeNotification` for a group of data manager changes. You would want to have a `DataMangerChangeTypeKey`.

For example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(DataMangerDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
    note in
    let changeType = note.userInfo![DataMangerChangeTypeKey] as String

    if changeType == DataMangerChangeTypeLocation {
        …
    } else if changeType == DataMangerChangeTypeOther {
        …
    }
}
```